# What are these ubiquitous cube-shaped crates seen throughout the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

Throughout the Star Wars franchise, a particular cube-shaped cargo crate is used as a common background prop. All visible faces of the crate contain a circle in the center and four straight lines emanating outward from the circle perpendicular to the edges of the face. A few examples can be seen in these screenshots taken from the Original Trilogy and *The Mandalorian* (apologies for the quality, these have been taken from other sources):

[image: The Mandalorian]
[image: Original Trilogy]
[image: Original Trilogy]

I can also personally recall seeing this design in the recent *Jedi: Fallen Order* video game and the *Rebels* cartoon.

Other types of cargo container have entries in Wookieepedia, such as the [Xizor series of cargo containers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Xizor_cargo_container), but I have been unable to find information on the design in question. I'm curious as to whether there is known information in Canon or Legends as to who the manufacturer of these crates is, their designation, etc.

Comment: The top ones appear to be weighed companion cubes

Comment: @Valorum Hmm, Aperture Science must have been around a lot longer than I thought! ;)

Comment: According to Fantasy Flight Games, in their Priority Supplies Battlefield Expansion for Star Wars Legion, they are simply supply crates. https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2018/7/12/reshape-the-battle/

Comment: In the Star Wars Imperial Assault board game these are '**loot crates**'. You can get 3-D printing instructions [here](https://www.myminifactory.com/it/object/3d-print-star-wars-imperial-assault-custom-replacement-loot-crate-tokens-31392). Any research should be looking for *star wars **storage** containers* not *cargo containers*.

Comment: Just how old is GLADOS?

Comment: Those are Weighted Storage Cubes, not Companion Cubes.

Comment: I'm going to guess they're Space Pokeballs.